# Development mode loads more than 450 files on every page reload

Tags: magento2

I've Magento 2 in Dev Mode. It's slow as hell but that's for another discussion.

My problem is that on every page and page reload magento requires +450 files.

E.g. An infinite number of `_module.less`, `_widget.less` and others, plus big images (part of the site content) my computer freezes/restarts at least 2 times a day because of all of these.

I was wondering if I'm missing something or Dev mode is supposed to require all these shitload of useless files every time?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that .less files will only be loaded like that if you have Magento set to client-side LESS compilation rather than server-side. Server-side is better for performance. See documentation for what they are and how they work: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Changing that will cut out a significant number of the requests in question.

Comment: yep, that did the trick.. from 455 to 130 files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in developer mode, this is correct, these files get generated on the fly. One thing you can do to speed it up is change your `memory_limit` in the various .htaccess files. By default it is set at 256MB. I upped all of mine to 2048MB and that sped things up considerably. You don't have to go that high if you don't have the memory available but I am running a vm and I can make it essentially anything I want.

In each file below, `php_value memory_limit` appears twice, so that's a total of 8 changes. In reality, you may not even need to edit all 4 but I didn't feel like doing them one at a time so I just changed them all.

```
.htaccess(root directory)
pub/.htaccess
vendor/magento/magento2-base/.htaccess
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/.htaccess
```

Also, check your php.ini file's `memory_limit` value because that will act as a cap on the max memory you can assign in the .htaccess files so you may need to update your php.ini as well.

I hope this helps!